# Methods in class returns value only inside them self JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the key of a `this.map` by value with method `getPoint()` in `board` class, but my code from what's reasons don't return value correctly to my class `BoardTest` only returns this inside a class `Board`. Why this happening ?

```
export default class Board {
constructor() {
        this.map = new Map();
        this.boardX = 20;
        this.boardY = 15;
    }
    add(_point, _creature) {
        let mapToString = ``;
        this.map.forEach((val, key) => {
            mapToString += ` ${JSON.stringify(key)} ${JSON.stringify(val)} `;
        });

        if (this.map.has(_point)) {
            throw "Exception: => To pole jest zajete, nie mozesz tam dodac jednostki";
        }
        if (_point.x > this.boardX || _point.y > this.boardY) {
            throw "Exception: => Creature nie zostala ruszona, wskazaany pkt jest poza mapa";
        }

        this.map.set(_point, _creature);

        if (mapToString.includes(JSON.stringify(_point))) {
            throw "Exception: => Klucz nie jest równy tej wartosci która powinna byc wpisana";
        }
    }
getVal(_point) {// <= this work 
        return this.map.get(_point);
}

getPoint(_creature) {// <= this not
   this.map.forEach((item, key) => {
        if (item === _creature) {
            console.log('key', key) //<= returns point `Point(0, 0)`
                return key;
        }
   })
}
}
```

```
export default class boardTest {
shouldReturnCorrectLocationForCreatureByCreature() {
        let board = new Board()
        let creature = new Creature();

        let unitTestPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        board.add(unitTestPoint, creature);


        console.log('board.getPoint(creature)', board.getPoint(creature)) //<= returns undefined
        if (board.getPoint(creature) !== unitTestPoint) {
            throw "Exception: => getPoint nie poprawnie zwraca Creature";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach()` method can't return anything.

You are only returning from the callback function passed to the `.forEach()` method. Return value of the callback function doesn't becomes the return value of the outer method.

You could use the `.entries()` method on the `map` object to get all its entries and then use `for-of` loop to return the key associated with a given value.

```
getPoint(_creature) {
   for (const [k, v] of this.map.entries()) {
      if (v === _creature) {
         return key;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your return statement works for `forEach` callback, not for `getPoint` function, you can use for example

```
getPoint(_creature) {
  return this.map.entries.find(([key, item]) => item === _creature)[0]
}
```

instead

or better keep it other way round - `creature` in key and `point` in value and get it in natural for `map` object way